# ((__m64*)&(ub8) ddata) giving error:lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

Tags: gcc, sse

I'm compiling other team's source code. I understand the error I'm getting, but I am not able to understand this line of the code (the code base is supposed to be correct).

```
data_vec = _mm_set1_epi64(*((__m64*)&(ub8) ddata));
```

What is (__m64*)? And what is it doing there?

EDIT: the error is: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

Comment: `_mm_set1_epi64x` takes an int64 instead of an `__m64` (MMX) operand; you might prefer using it (but check that your compiler provides it in 32bit mode.)

Answer (score 2):

It's a cast to a pointer. Refer to [MSDN for information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48z274sd(v=vs.90).aspx) on the SSE2 types and functions used.

The error is unrelated. A casted value is no lvalue anymore, while `&` may only be used on lvalues. Remove the `(ub8)` cast, or even better find the person or macro that generated that code in the first place.

Comment: I was being a noob with the (__m64*)... but why a pointer is being put in front of ampersand?

Comment: yes, it is a pointer. I'm hesitant in removing the cast (it's used in like 3000 places in the project file)...

Comment: @theninety'er Was that VC++ code by chance? IIRC, MSVC has lvalue casts as a compiler extension. Not sure how it interacts with address taking though. Both returning the first byte's and last byte's address sounds reasonable.

Comment: So I decided to remove (ub8), and yes it fixed the problem. But I haven't checked the functionality...